# Gaining access to Google Maps Android API Util Lib with Android Studio & OS X

Tags: android, macos, google-maps, heatmap

I need access to the Google Maps Android Heatmap Utility (note; this is not standard google maps API). See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap

So far I have

1. Added dependency compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' to build.gradle (Modile: app) file.

[image: build.gradle depencenies]

2. Added the following code to my project:

   ```
   private void addHeatMap() {
       List<LatLng> list = null;
       // Get the data: latitude/longitude positions of police stations.
       try {
           list = readItems(R.raw.police_stations);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
       HeatmapTileProvider mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
               .data(list)
               .build();
       // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
       mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new     TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));}
   ```

   3. Added the two imports
      [image: google map import]
   4. Set $PATH and $ANDROID_HOME variables
      [image: Path and android home vars]
   5. Downloaded Google Repo & Google Play services
      [image: Google Repo & Play Services]

Here's the setup guide for OS X with Android Studio:
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/#start

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what I did, but it is working now.

I also needed to add the imports:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlay;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions;
```